# What is this perfumed arbust and can it survive deep frost?

Tags: identification, cold-weather

I saw below arbust in Geneva. It was planted into a hail behind a metallic fence. It has started blossoming lately in the beginning of June.

I wander what it is. Does anyone know?

[image]
[image]

It has great perfume and I'm considering planting one at my place. But I live 250 meters (820 feet) above Geneva, and temperatures can be -20 deg.C (-4 deg. F) for a night or two. Could it be a possibility for my garden?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Trachelospermum jasminoides, an evergreen twining climber. Unfortunately, its only hardy down to -10 degC as a minimum temperature, so if your winter temperatures regularly fall lower than this, its not a good choice.

https://www.rhs.org.uk/Plants/18287/Trachelospermum-jasminoides/Details